# How To Fix Selenium Traceback (most recent call last): print(contact.text()) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Am Creating Whatsapp Script Which It Saves All My Whatsapp Contacts Name In Selenium.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(contact.text())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
input("Qr Code Done? : ")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

contact = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3q9s6')
print(contact.text()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_elements
```

returns a `list` in Selenium-Python bindings. So,  you can not use `.text` on a list.

Either do the following :

1. use `find_element` instead.

**Like :**

```
contact = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3q9s6')
print(contact.text)
```

2. If you wanna use `find_elements`, then do this :

   ```
   contact = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3q9s6')
   for c in contact:
      print(c.text)
   ```

Comment: First sample, shouldn't it be `.text` ?

Answer (score 1):

`find_element_by_class_name` is on plural, it finds all of the element**s**, try:

```
contact = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3q9s6')
print(contact.text)
```

You where only a character off, close enough :-)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.text` ?

Comment: @frianH Edited mine sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

`.find_element_*` (without `s`) for finding single element, or this is matching the first element if in the web page there are multiple element with same specific:

```
contact = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3q9s6')
print(contact.text)
```

But your code, `.find_elements_*` (with `s`), it will return a list.
You can achieve with this by accessing the index:

```
contact = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3q9s6')

#first element
print(contact[0].text)
```

Note, to grab the text it should `.text` not `.text()`